# How to retrieve the fully qualified name from certain functions while parsing the python file

Tags: python, nlp, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I've noticed that there's a '**qualname**' for functions to get their fully qualified name. However, what I'm trying to achieve is to extract a functions call sequence from a given python file, which means to get the fully qualified name while reading the file, but not execute it. Here's an example of the problem.

Given code:

```
import libA
class A():
    bar = libA.Bar()
    bar.functionA()
```

I'm expecting the output of: libA.Bar.functionA.

Is there a way to use the **inspect** or **ast** tool to solve this issue?